# object object error when trying to return value

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong here I have a feeling it has something to do with the json encode return? I get an [object object] return error in my code.

Here's the PHP:

```
<?php
require_once('../config.php');

if(isset($_GET['parcel_id'])) {
    $db = new ezSQL_mysql(DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, DB_HOST);

    //count number of comments for the id
    $data2 = $db->get_results("select count(*) from comments where parcel_id=" . $_GET['parcel_id']);
    echo json_encode($data2);
}

?>
```

Jquery/JSON:

```
        $('#searchTable tr').click(function(){
            var parcel_id = $(this).attr('id');
            $('#ParcelNumber').html(parcel_number);

            var parcel_number = $('td:first', $(this).parents('tr')).text();
            $.ajax({
                url: "classes/get-apn-count-comments.php?parcel_id=" + parcel_id,
                type: "GET",
                data: { parcel_id : parcel_id },
                dataType: 'json',
                error: function(SMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    alert("An error has occurred making the request: " + errorThrown);
                },
                success: function(data2){
                    //do stuff here on success
                    //$('#ParcelNumber').html(data[0]["apn"]);
                    $('#ViewComments').html('View ' + data2[0] + ' Comments');
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: `[object object]` is not an error, it's what happens when you try to turn something into a string that can't handle that. Try using `console.log(errorThrown)` and press F12 to see the result in your browser's debug console.

Comment: which line the error, please give the error output

Comment: @IMSoP where do I add that code? Into the php? The php works perfect I am just having a hard time returning the result :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#ViewComments').html('View ' + data2[0] + ' Comments');
```

In the line above, data2[0] is actually a json object containing one field (count).

1) In the PHP, change the query to:

```
"select count(*) AS count from comments where parcel_id=" . $_GET['parcel_id']
```

(this will make it easier to reference in step 2)

2) In the jQuery, change it to:

```
$('#ViewComments').html('View ' + data2[0].count + ' Comments');
```

This should properly reference the bit you're looking for.